# How to use try/catch to avoid throwing FileNotFoundException in java

Tags: java, try-catch, filenotfoundexception, throws

I am trying to output a file scanner object from my method.  This is a school assignment and I am specifically instructed to NOT throw any exceptions, but use try/catch instead.  The assignment requires that the command line prompt the user for a file to scan.  If the file does not exist, we are supposed to tell the user, then prompt them for a file again.  If the file does exist, then the method returns a scanner object that scans the file.

My code works, but it is not clean.  It involves 2 methods.  This is my code so far:

```
public static Scanner getInputScanner (Scanner console) {
    File inputFile = null;
    Scanner input = null;
    try {
        inputFile = getFile(inputFile, console);
        input = new Scanner (inputFile);
        return input;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        try {
            return input = new Scanner (getFile (inputFile, console));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
            System.out.println("An error has occured.");
            return input;
        }
    }

}

public static File getFile (File inputFile, Scanner console) {

    System.out.println("Enter input file: ");
    inputFile = new File (console.nextLine());

    while (!inputFile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("File does not exist.");
        System.out.print("Enter input file: ");
        inputFile = new File (console.nextLine());
    }
    return inputFile;
}
```

The problem with the code is that the output looks like this:

Enter input file:

File does not exist.

Enter input file:

It then is waiting for the user's input.  I don't want the output to have the 2 lines of code before the last line though.

Can anybody explain why my code is outputting these 2 lines?
Also, is there a simpler solution to getting an input file without throwing the FileNotFoundException?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the code calling these methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly,
your program outputs these lines when you run it,
no matter what,
without you getting a chance to actually enter a filename.

> ```
> Enter input file:
> File does not exist.
> ```

And then the programs asks you again:

> ```
> Enter input file:
> ```

And you don't want the first two lines above, right?
This can happen for example if the `Scanner console` you received has an unread newline in it.
You haven't posted that part of the code,
so it's hard to tell, but this is a common gotcha with `Scanner`.
Before calling `getInputScanner`,
make sure the `Scanner console` is ready to use,
with no unread garbage still buffered in it.

As for the second part of your question,
yes this can be written simpler and better, for example:

```
public static Scanner getInputScanner(Scanner console) {
    try {
        File inputFile = getExistingFile(console);
        return new Scanner(inputFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new AssertionError("The file is expected to exist (was supposed to be verified earlier)");
    }
}

public static File getExistingFile(Scanner console) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter input file: ");
        File inputFile = new File(console.nextLine());

        if (inputFile.exists()) {
            return inputFile;
        }
        System.out.println("File does not exist.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input janos.  Yes, you are correct.  My program executes the first 2 lines of code no matter what.

Comment: Also, thank you for the code you responded with.  It is definitely more concise.  I used it just now, but unfortunately, I get the same output.  I think you may be correct about the scanner having some unread tokens buffered in it.

Comment: Before calling this method, calling `nextLine` on the scanner might be a simple fix

Comment: Janos, this was the problem.  All I did was add a console.nextLine() before the "Enter input file: " prompt and it all looks good.  Thanks so much for the tip.  I spent hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

It execute below line as soon the getFile() being called.

System.out.print("Enter input file: ");

Since no file exist, the below lines keeps on executing :

while (!inputFile.exists()) {

```
    System.out.println ("File does not exist.");
    System.out.print("Enter input file: ");
```

You can use throws() instead of try/catch, then caller will take care of exception.

Answer (score 0):

Had to consume whatever junk was being carried over from the scanner by inserting a Scanner.nextLine() before getting user input.  Final code looks like this:

```
public static Scanner getInputScanner(Scanner console) {
    try {
        File inputFile = getExistingFile(console);
        return new Scanner(inputFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new AssertionError("The file is expected to exist (was supposed to be verified earlier)");
    }
}

public static File getExistingFile(Scanner console) {
    while (true) {
        console.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter input file: ");
        File inputFile = new File(console.nextLine());

        if (inputFile.exists()) {
            return inputFile;
        }
        System.out.println("File does not exist.");
    }
}
```